# Loading spring XML from location different from classpath

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I am trying to read spring xml using ClassPathXmlApplicationContext class as below.

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:../WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
    Service service = (Service ) context.getBean("service");
```

But I am getting FileNotFound exception. dispatcher-servlet.xml is located under WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml. If I move the file to Src folder, it works fine.

I tried different ways like

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:../WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");

 ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml");
```

But these don't work. Can someone provide some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

from the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch05s07.html):

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/appContext.xml");
```

Comment: how do I give the relative path? below path doesn't work `classpath:../WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml`

Comment: AFAIK, classpath does not have a .. directory. Think of a classpath as a sort of virtual / (root) file system. If you need your address to be relative, then you probably need to use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Or use `ServletContextResource` if you need to do this in code. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextResource.html).